# How to compute a complex integral of $x \: dz$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification, complex-integration, line-integrals

I'm working through chapter 4 of Alfohrs, and the first exercise is computing the integral $\int_\gamma x \: dz$ where $\gamma$ is the directed line segment from $0$ to $1+i$. What, exactly, does this mean?

I know that by definition, $\int_\gamma f(z)\:dz = \int_a^b f(z(t)) z'(t) \:dt$; however, I'm not quite sure what to do with this definition here. One thing that seems to be the case is $f$ is probably implied to be in the form $x + iy$ (is this a fair assumption?) If so, I could use the expansion $\int_\gamma f(z)\:dz = \int_\gamma (u dx - v dy) + i \int_\gamma (u dy + v dx)$, which would after substitution become $\int_\gamma x dx + i \int_\gamma x dy$.

If I can indeed have it in this form, I need to somehow parametrize $\gamma$, correct? My attempt here is saying that $\gamma(t) = t + it$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Then I get that $\int_\gamma x dx + i \int_\gamma x dy = \int_0^1 x(t)x'(t)dt + i\int_0^1 x(t)y'(t)dt = \int_0^1 t dt + i\int_0^1 t dt = (t^2/2)\mid_0^1 + (t^2/2)\mid_0^1 = (t^2)\mid_0^1 = 1^2=0^2=1$.

Is any of this reasoning correct?

**Edit**

Fixed my last calculation in response to mrsamy's answer: it's now $\int_\gamma x dx + i \int_\gamma x dy = \int_0^1 x(t)x'(t)dt + i\int_0^1 x(t)y'(t)dt = \int_0^1 t dt + i\int_0^1 t dt = (t^2/2)\mid_0^1 + i(t^2/2)\mid_0^1 = 1/2 + 1/2 \cdot i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the first step is parametrizing the curve $\gamma$.

Instead of $\gamma(t)$, you write $z(t)=t+it$, $0\le t\le 1$. So $z'(t)=1+i$ and thus
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)dz=\int_0^1 f(z(t))z'(t)dt=\int_0^1t(1+i)dt=(1+i)\int_0^1tdt=\frac12(1+i).
$$

You miss an $i$ in your calculation.

Comment: Thanks so much! Just to clarify, how did you obtain the first equality? Was my step that $\int_\gamma x dx = \int_0^1 x(t) x'(t) dt$ correct?

Comment: @M.L.: you are welcome. It is simply $\int_0^1 f(z(t))z'(t)dt=\int_0^1f(t+it)(1+i)dt=\int_0^1t(1+i)dt$.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a good way of thinking of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning seems to be mostly fine.

$\int_\gamma x\ dx + \int_\gamma x\ dy$

$x$ is the real part of the parameterization of $\gamma,$ y is the imaginary part.

$x = t, dx = dt\\
y = it, dy = i\ dt$

$\int_0^1 t\ dt + \int_0^1 it\ dt\\
\frac 12 + \frac 12 i$

Comment: Thank you! Where does your first expression come from? If we were to separate the real and imaginary parts of a function $f = u + iv$, wouldn't we get that $\int_\gamma f dz = \int_\gamma (u dx - v dy) + i \int_\gamma (u dy + v dx)$? Or are you using something different here?

Comment: Oh, is it the case that you're breaking up the parametrization of $\gamma$ into real and imaginary parts, as opposed to a function of $\gamma$?

Comment: Yes, I broke up the parameterization into real and imaginary parts.